# Amazon S3 + Cloud Front

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I want to store my files on S3 + Cloud Front Fro CDN

I know that the cost of S3 Storage, but it has transfer price

my question is that If I want to use CloudFront, should I pay both bandwidth price for Cloud Front And S3 ? or I just pay for  CloudFront bandwidth ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Amazon S3 or Amazon EC2 as an origin server (server to store your original files to be served throught CDN), data transferred from the origin server to edge locations (Amazon CloudFront “origin fetches”) will be billed at a lower price than Internet data transfer out of Amazon S3 or Amazon EC2. Data Transfer out of Amazon CloudFront to your origin server will be billed at the “Regional Data Transfer Out to Origin” rates listed at http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/

Answer (score 0):

Cloudfront is all about speed of access. Whenever you upgrade an S3 bucket to Cloudfront, your data is immediately pushed out to their edge locations around the world. This gives users much faster access to the data, but this speed comes at a cost. Each edge location has an associated cost in addition to the regular Amazon S3 fees. Very active or very large files can generate significant fees.

Therefore, you have to pay for both.

For pricing details:
https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/ 
https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/